In an OBB NightJet Comfort Couchette Compartment, is there any difference between booking 4 beds and a full compartment?
I am booking a trip on OBB NightJet in the new Comfort couchette compartments (scroll down to "Comfort Couchettes" in the link).
We are a family of four, so if we book one berth each, we fill up the entire compartment. Still, when booking, I am presented with two options: to buy four individual berths or to reserve a private compartment. The private compartment is considerably more expensive than the four individual berths.
Is there any point in buying the private compartment? Am I right in assuming that the result would be exactly the same if I booked the four berths? The website mentions that, with the four-berths option, "other travellers in the compartment possible or open-plan carriage." But, in our case, we are booking four berths in a four-berth couchette, so no other traveller is possible, and the Comfort couchette car definitely has no open plan.
Example for OBB NJ 40294 on November 7 from Florence to Vienna on NightJet's website:


Are those "Individual Seat " prices of €139 per traveller price (total €556) whereas the "Private compartment" is €204 for the complete compartment for all four travelers?

No, progressing with the booking shows that €139 is the total for the four travellers. (Thanks for your comment.)
